# How to call a method with a dynamic parameter

Tags: angularjs

I'm making an app for healthcare and we have a page that will show messages.
I'm just testing some stuff out for now so it's not that advanced yet.

```
<div ng-controller="loginController as loginCtrl">
                <div ng-init="messageCtrl.getMessages(loginCtrl.user._id)">
                    <td>{{message.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{message.content}}</td>
                    <td>{{message.patientId}}</td>
                </div>
</div>

function getMessages(userID) {
        alert(userID);
        messageFactory.getMessages(userID)
            .then(
                function success(response) {
                    vm.messages = response.data;

                },
                function (error, status, header, config) {
                    vm.errorMsg = error;
                    vm.status = status;
                });
    }
```

I want to get the messages by userID, so I'll only show the messages this logged in user has. I can't seem to get this to work.

When I alert the userID I get 'undefined'.
How can I get the userID in the controller?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @koox00 it does show a value when I use it in my view but it just doesn't seem to pass it to my controller.

Comment: seems strange.. I would make a different approach btw. I would get my logged in user using a service so you can inject it everywhere. save the ID in localstorage maybe after login and then pull it from there everytime.

Comment: hm, how do you get the user? I mean if it's an api call then it is normal that at the time of rendering ( ng-init call) userID is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Change your function in JS as below,

```
  $scope.getMessages = function(userID)
    {
          alert(userID);
    }
```

and view as

```
 <div ng-init="getMessages(user._id)">
```

Here is the working [`application`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/n7n1tw77/5/)

Comment: Doesn't work, it breaks the application and every dynamic value is shown as text :(

Comment: It doesn't give the value of {{loginCtrl.user._id}} to the method in my methodController.

Comment: can you create a plunker for your issue?